# AS3 #1067 Implict Coercion of a value of type flash.utils.timer to an unrelated type Function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer, flashdevelop

I've been getting this error and I have no clue how to fix it, it works in another class so it should work here, right? (I moved it from that class to this one) The only difference is that this class extends 'Game' and the other class extends 'MovieClip'

```
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type flash.utils:Timer to an unrelated type Function.

public static var timeLeft;

public function GamePlay() {
    // Start timer
    var timeCounter:Timer = new Timer(1000, timeLeft)
    timeCounter.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timeCounter);
    timeCounter.start();
}

// Handle time counter
public function timeCounter(e:TimerEvent):void {
    timeLeft--;
    trace(timeLeft);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function and your `Timer` are both called `timeCounter`, so it thinks you're trying to pass the `Timer` as a function (hence the error). You should rename one of the two, here I've renamed the function:

```
public static var timeLeft;

// Start timer
var timeCounter:Timer = new Timer(1000, timeLeft)
timeCounter.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timeCountHandler);
timeCounter.start();

// Handle time counter
public function timeCountHandler(e:TimerEvent):void {
    timeLeft--;
    trace(timeLeft);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give Timer object and listener function different names:

```
public static var timeLeft:int;

var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000, timeLeft)
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timeCounter);
timer.start();

public function timeCounter(e:TimerEvent):void {
    timeLeft--;
    trace(timeLeft);
}
```

I assume timeLeft is set somewhere else?